# Pandas merge_asof Question: one-to-multiple merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes by nearest time point.
I tried `merge_asof`. However, the issue is two entries have the same time point, then
`merge_asof` will only merge one entry into the final dataframe.

Here is an example:

df_A:

```
  time     ticker     price
09:10:13    VOD       110.96
```

df_B:

```
  time     ticker     volume
09:10:12    VOD       35412
09:10:12    VOD       12343
```

I tried:

```
pd.merge(df_A, df_B, how = 'left', on = ['time'], by=['ticker'], direction='backward')
```

And it only returns:

```
  time     ticker     price    volume
09:10:13    VOD       110.96    12343
```

As you can see one entry/row is deleted here.
**I want to use merge_asof and keep all entries under the same nearest time point.**

Ideal output:

```
  time     ticker    price      volume
09:10:12    VOD     110.96      35412
09:10:12    VOD     110.96      12343
```

Any advise?

Comment: merge don't have **direction** attribute, as indicated in your example. and merge_asof don't have **how** attribute

Comment: merge_asof requires merge dtypes to be numeric data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a double `merge`, first with the `merge_asof`, then a classical `merge`. The trick is to identify the duplicates in the asof merged right DataFrame:

```
df_B2 = df_B.assign(idx=df_B.groupby('time').ngroup())

out = (pd
 .merge_asof(df_A, df_B2, on='time', by='ticker', direction='backward')
 .merge(df_B2, on=['ticker', 'idx'])
 #.drop(columns='idx')
)
```

*NB. I used `datetime` columns for the example*

output:

```
               time_x ticker   price  volume_x  idx              time_y  volume_y
0 2022-06-27 09:10:13    VOD  110.96     12343    0 2022-06-27 09:10:12     35412
1 2022-06-27 09:10:13    VOD  110.96     12343    0 2022-06-27 09:10:12     12343
```

used input:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'time': [Timestamp('2022-06-27 09:10:13')],
                     'ticker': ['VOD'], 'price': [110.96]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'time': [Timestamp('2022-06-27 09:10:12'), Timestamp('2022-06-27 09:10:12')],
                     'ticker': ['VOD', 'VOD'],
                     'volume': [35412, 12343]})
```